# wxPython app frozen using py2exe looses visual styles on Windows 10. Any pointers?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, py2exe

I've been scratching my head for the past couple of days trying to get my wxPython GUI app to look right when converted to and exe.

The python version im using is Python27 64bit, wxPython 3.0.2 (classic) and p2exe 0.6.9 (64 bit).

-When I run my application using the Python Interpreter the app looks and functions as expected.

-When I freeze it into an exe using **py2exe** and run it on a **Windows 7** machine the application looks and functions as expected.

-When I run the same frozen app on a **Windows 10** machine the application looks like a Windows 98 app and some of the functionality of the Windows file (open/save) dialog are buggy as shown below.

[image]

Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtM-bXPshCFMV6MALE2NdJUm4_00CXeP/view?usp=sharing) to my set up file

I have tried suggestions from the following threads with no success so far.

- [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605312/wxpython-py2exe-exe-file-old-window)
- [Frank's blog](https://franks543.blogspot.com/2007/08/wxpython-py2exe-too-ugly.html)
- [The Python Haven](https://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/how-to-get-xp-styles-on-wxpython-apps-made-with-py2exe/)
- [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764410/how-to-make-a-exe-for-python-with-good-graphics)

Can anyone help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem also. Your test system is loading the wrong dlls.

Remove any msvc*.dll, *.manifest (and also gdiplus.dll and w9xpopen.exe if you haven't already since you need them only for windows 95/98/XP compatibility) from your frozen application dir, Windows 10 probably already has the required dlls.

If that doesn't work try also removing your manifest in your setup (setup.py) file (manifest='...' and 'other_resources': [(24,1,manifest)]}] ) and you will be ok (only for x64 versions of py2exe).